# Limit number of Checkbox list items and add scrolling

Tags: html, css, webforms

I have two checkbox lists in asp.net that I am populating dynamically using a drop down list,

now both are in divs, one contains all fruit names and one contains only fruit names in a specific crate.

**If there are a lot of items in my checkbox list then it overflows out of the div, is there any way I can fix it please ?**

This is markup

```
   <div class="list1">
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Available fruits" />
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
    </div>
    <div class="list2">
        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="fruits in a crate" />
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
    </div>
```

CSS

```
    .list1
    {
        clear: both; 
        float: left; 
        width: 290px;
        height: 190px;
overflow-y:scroll;
    }

    .list2
    {
        float:right;
        width: 290px;
        height: 190px;
overflow-y:scroll;
    }
```

**Update**

*I tried adding this to div class `overflow-y:scroll;` and `overflow:scroll;`
I also put my checkbox list to a seperate div and added above but no gain ONLY pain sir.*

Comment: why dindt you declare any hight

Comment: I had to change my question, sorry

Comment: Mh you could add a max-height:100%; ?

Comment: I can but since checkbox list is in a messagebox and rest of screen is blocked, i would like to add a scroll bar instead

Comment: why not just add `overflow-y:scroll` to your `.list1` and `.list2`?

Comment: Added but no gain, only pain sir :(

Comment: you could give the cbl a class and then assign a height and overflow scroll to that

Comment: thanks, I tried both, still no gain only pain sir

Comment: can you post the rendered html

Comment: tried overflow-y:auto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set an explicit height, you may be looking to add `overflow:scroll;`

Comment: Odd, as that should do the trick... You're sure it's not cached css?